# 'firebase serve' does not show certain errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a hard time understanding how to properly debug Firebase http functions here. Say I have this code

```
exports.buggyFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const result = foo.bar.baz
  return res.status(200).send(result)
})
```

If I run this through `firebase serve`, the log will give me zero error about `foo.bar.baz` and simply return an empty result. In node, it will give me a TypeError. It seems that `firebase serve` will only alert me on parsing error, which is not exactly what I expect from an Express process.

Is this because of differences between *node v6.11.6* & *node v8.9.1* ? What can I do to see these errors? The `--debug` flag does not seems to help

Comment: If you are not using NVM I can highly recommend it, so you can run the code simulating node v6. What is foo - just an object or?

Comment: Yeah I use nvm as well, thanks for the tip tho. In the example foo does not exists, as in, this is litterally the line in the function not a placeholder for anything else

Comment: Ahh ok - I will give it a try later in my functions repo